# Search part of tuple list

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I am trying to do a list comprehension of a tuples list based on another list of tuples with partial match.

```
x = [((1,1),(1,1),(1,2)),
     ((2,1),(1,3),(2,9)),
     ((2,1),(2,3),(2,9))]
y = [(2,1),(1,3)]
[i for i in x for k in y if k in i]
```

e.g. in this x is a list of tuples & y is the desired list of tuples. If y is found in any of the items in the list of tuples in x, it should return that item.

Result is: `[((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9)), ((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9)), ((2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 9))]`

But I want only : `[((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9))]`

I tried with single tuple & it gave the desired result. But not sure why it doesn't work when I pass a tuple list.

```py
x = [((1,1),(1,1),(1,2)),
     ((2,1),(1,3),(2,9)),
     ((2,1),(2,3),(2,9))]
y = (2,1)
[i for i in x if y in i]
```

Result: `[((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9)), ((2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 9))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
x = [
    ((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)),
    ((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9)),
    ((2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 9)),
]
y = [(2, 1), (1, 3)]

print([t for t in x if not set(y).difference(t)])
```

output:

```
[((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9))]
```

If you subtract tuples inside `x` from `y` with set operations, if all the sub tuples are present, you'll end up with an empty set, so you want that tuple.

You could also write `if set(y).issubset(t)` instead of `if not set(y).difference(t)` part.(borrowed from @kellyBundy's answer)

> What if I want any tpl of y to be true but not all.

```py
print([t for t in x if set(y).intersection(t)])
```

Comment: - I liked all 3 answers, I accepted yours as it was easy for me to understand. What if I want any tpl of y to be true but not all. I can use Chris answer with any(). But I was hoping if the subset can have any arguments that can handle that as well.

Comment: You would use a set _intersection_.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't have to be a comprehension:

```
[*filter({*y}.issubset, x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

`all` is the ticket here, determining if *all* tuples in `y` are in each element in `x`.

```
[
  tpl 
  for tpl in x 
  if all(tpl2 in tpl 
         for tpl2 in y)
]
# [((2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 9))]
```

Comment: Or sets, if `y` is sufficiently large compared to `x` items.

Comment: @SUTerliakov - can you please elaborate as to why or how sets will help? For my education.